# How to combine multiple arrays of the same size in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

If I have 3 or more arrays I want to combine into one, how do I do that in ruby? Would it be a variation on zip?

For example, I have

`a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]`

and I would like to have an array that looks like

`[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[a,b,c].transpose
```

is all you need.  I prefer this to `zip` 50% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) as below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
a.zip(b, c)
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```